# how to call a function inside a function from another class in java?

Tags: java

I have two classes 
First class m passing string as argument to the other class. But now I want to use the function from the other class.
previously;

```
class ClassOne{ 
    public funclass(URL, int a){ 
      //do something
    }
}

class ClassTwo{
  public getClass() {
     //do something else 
  }
}
```

I want to use the getClass in place of the URL.

Comment: Please bring your code in order. It is unreadable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why your question is not quite good: the code is unreadable and won't compile. It is also not quite clear what are you asking.

Comment: Neither of those functions take a `String` as a parameter. Please show your actual code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow @lexicore advice.   You need to make `getClass()` return URL and use by `funclass(new classTwo().getClass(), "a string")`

Comment: @c0der Make `getClass()` return `URL`? How?

Comment: Any method must return a value. If `URL` is a String than `public String getClass() {
     /*do something*/
  }`

Comment: @lexicore no we send URL as a argument

Comment: @c0der Are you sure String getClass() will even compile?

Comment: *no we send URL as a argument* - not sure what you reply to and what you mean.

Comment: @lexicore sorry, you are right. Bad choice of name. `class ClassTwo{
   public String getClassUrl() {/* do something */   }
}`